# If you destroy a civ, do you still get the "You declared war on our friend!" penalty?

Tags: civilization-4, civilization-4-beyond-the-sword

As per the tag, this is in Civilization 4 (BTS).

Answer (score 1):

Honestly speaking, I do not remember 100%, but as far as I remember, you get this penalty on a war declaration and it remains even after the civ is destroyed. I would bet on this.